# Jersey ContainerRequestFilter is only working in broswer Mode

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, restful-architecture, tomcat8, jersey-client

I'm experimenting with Jersey 2.17 trying to create RESTful Web Services, I read the [Jersey User guide 2.17](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html) and followed the instructions in chapter 10 to create filters, my Problem is that the filter is working perfectly when the resource is called from a browser, however when I call the resource from a java SE test client the filter does not get triggered. ,the filter is PreMatching ContainerRequestFilter, do you have any idea if there is an extra setting required to enable the filter across the whole resource, I mean make it work even if the call is made form a test client instead of a browser.

This is by requestFilter

```
package com.vogella.jersey.fist;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@PreMatching
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext arg0) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(" Media Type : "+arg0.getMediaType());
        System.out.println("Method Type : "+arg0.getMethod());
        System.out.println("Method length : "+arg0.getLength());
        System.out.println("request time : "+arg0.getDate());
        System.out.println(" message : "+arg0.toString());
        arg0.abortWith(Response
                .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .entity("User cannot access the resource.")
                .build());
    }
}
```

and this is myApplicationFile :

```
package com.vogella.jersey.fist;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        // Resources.
        packages(Hello.class.getPackage().getName());

        // register(LoggingFilter.class);
        register(RequestFilter.class);
        //  register(ResponseFilter.class);
    }
}
```

and finally this is my web.xml:

```
[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.fist</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.fist.RequestFilter</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>][2]
```

below is my Test Client Code .

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
// client.register(MyJAXBContextProvider.class);
WebTarget service = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.fist").build());
        System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("todo").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).get(String.class));

Todo a = service.path("rest").path("todo").request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Todo.class) ; 
        System.out.println(a.getDescription());
```

Can anybody tell me how to get past that problem? 
PS : I'm using TomCat8 as a server.

Comment: Can you show the client code. Have you checked for any exceptions thrown? Have you checked the response status from the client code?

Comment: Also, get rid of this init-param `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters`. It's garbage. That's only for Jersey 1.x

Comment: I'll share the client code. ,as for exceptions I do not get any exception in the client or server side, it appears that Jersey ignoring the filter if the request made from none browser based application

Comment: Just to be clear, the calling of the filter is not dependent on the type of client. There is something else going on that we are not seeing.

Comment: i have added the Client application code to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK , so adding @Provider  anottation at top of my RequestFilter class ( before @PreMathcing ) solved my Issue .

thank you peeskillet